# IE 8 и ниже. Как перебросить на другой сайт эти браузеры

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте! Сделал сайт и он криво отображается на ie8 и ниже, на всех других нормально. Как можно сделать проверку на браузер и перебросить на другую альтернативную страницу сайта автоматически???

Comment: Для кроссбраузерного сайта, лучше использовать feature detection чем browser detection (не знаю как правильно сказать на русском)

Comment: @PeterOlson, да, но к старым IE это явно не относится.

Comment: @Qwertiy Почему?

Comment: Потому что поддержка ими всяких фич уже никогда не изменится, как и комплект багов, которые могут быть несовместимы с твоим кодом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На клиенте можно перекинуть. У `jQuery` есть [хороший плагин](https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin)
Ну и...

```
if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 9){
   location.href = 'http://domain.com';
}
```

Comment: не работает....

Comment: Что именно не работает? Не срабатывает условие? Не перебрасывает на другой сайт? Выдает ошибки? Расскажи - тебе помогут.

Comment: не перебрасывает на сайт это условие, я как понимаю это php скрипт?

Comment: Конечно нет. Клиентский js скрипт.

Answer (score 2):

Используй условные комментарии:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>Разметка тут видима только для IE6<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->А тут - для IE строго больше 8 и всех остальных<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>Для IE8-<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Ну и чем не угодил ответ?

Comment: От того, что @Vadizar спустя полтора года переписал этот ответ добавив пример кода и поставил минус, мой ответ стал плохим?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, добавил :(

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в шаблон добавить следующий код:

```
<?php
    $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if (stripos($user_agent, 'MSIE 6.0') !== false && stripos($user_agent, 'MSIE 8.0') === false && stripos($user_agent, 'MSIE 7.0') === false) {
        if (!isset($HTTP_COOKIE_VARS["ie"])) {
            setcookie("ie", "yes", time()+60*60*24*360);
            header ("Location: /нужная страница");
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Не работает почемуто

Answer (score 0):

Рабочее решение на чистом JS для всех IE, версия которых меньше девятой:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
    </script>
<![endif] -->
```