# Подключение script

Tags: html, веб-программирование, internet-explorer

Подскажите как подключить код, так что бы его видели все браузеры и ie9 и выше, но что бы его не видео ie8 и ниже?

Для ie8 и ниже подключаю вот так:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
  <script src="js.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/429348/178988

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно использовать другую форму условного комментария, при которой только проверка оказывается комментарием, а содержимое - нет:

```html
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->IE строго больше 8 и все остальные браузеры<!--<![endif]-->
```

> Не подскажите откуда вот это `<!-->` это же не обычный вроде как комментарий и в конце совсем не понятно закрывается.

`<!--...-->` - это нормальный комментарий. Вместо многоточия может быть что угодно (точнее, стандарт запрещает использовать `--` внутри комментария, хотя браузеры съедят, да и к вопросу это не относится). Так вот, вместо `...` ничто не запрещает мне поставить `<!` - это всего лишь комментарий.

Т. е. для нормальных браузеров обычный комментарий закрылся. Как это парсит IE, я не знаю. Предположу, что делит на `<!--[if gt IE 8]>` и `<!-->`. Что для него значит второе - не знаю. Ну либо они просто изначально такую форму заложили (хотя неясно, почему не просто `<!--[if gt IE 8]-->`) для совместимости. В общем, надо просто знать, что там так можно :)

PS: [Ещё варианты](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/429348/178988).

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!! Кажется это работает, сейчас проверю, и отмечу как ответ.

Comment: Вот пишут про другие браузеры, а снипет с таким кодом `<!--[if gt IE 8]><script src="js.min.js"></script><![endif]-->` в html на FF53 не грузит файл `js.min.js` :)

Comment: Я проверил на FF51 все работает, мне кажется у вас не работает потому что-то ваш код написанный здесь не соответствует коды который написал @Qwertiy

Comment: Сейчас обновляю до FF53 гляну.

Comment: @Visman, ты приводишь код НЕ из моего ответа. Сравни мои `]><!-->` & `<!--<![endif]-->` со своими `]>` & `<![endif]-->`.

Comment: проверил на FF53 все норм. Вот это <!--> это просто супер, все работает на отлично и валидацию w3c проходит. Еще раз спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Не подскажите откуда вот это  <!--> это же не обычный вроде как комментарий и в конце совсем не понятно закрывается.

Comment: @Dima, дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой костыль с условным комментарием и `document.write()`:

```html
<script>var IE9plus_and_All = true;</script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script>IE9plus_and_All = false;</script><![endif]-->
<script>if(IE9plus_and_All){document.write('<scr'+'ipt src="js.min.js"></scr'+'ipt>');}</script>
```